# How to display data from three different entities or classes in JFXTreeTableView

Tags: javafxports

I have three classes, Countries, Cities and Communities.
The Countries class relates one to many to Cities, and in Countries I have a List attribute where I store the cities. The Cities class relates from one to many to Localities, and in Cities I have a List attribute where I store the localities. My question?.
How to show in JFXTreeTableView a country like Root with its cities and the city with its communities?

Entities

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY) 
public class GS_TablaPaises  extends RecursiveTreeObject<GS_TablaPaises> implements Serializable{

    @ GeneratedValue ( strategy = GenerationType.TABLE , generator = 
    "codigoIdPais" )
    @ SequenceGenerator ( name = "codigoIdPais" , initialValue = 100 , 
    allocationSize = 1 )   

    @Id
    private int codigoIdPais;
    private SimpleStringProperty nombrePais;
    private SimpleStringProperty capitalPais;
    private SimpleStringProperty dominioInternetPais;
    private SimpleBooleanProperty filtrarPais;


    // establecemos la relacion de uno a muchos con la tabla ciudades
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = GS_TablaCiudades.class, mappedBy = "paises", 
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<GS_TablaCiudades> listaCiudades = new ArrayList< 
    GS_TablaCiudades>();

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // constructor vacio
    public GS_TablaPaises() {
        super();
    }   

    // constructor con parametros
    public GS_TablaPaises(Integer codigoIdPais, String nombrePais, String 
    capitalPais, String dominioInternetPais, Boolean  filtrarPais, 
    List<GS_TablaCiudades> listaCiudades) { 
        this.codigoIdPais = codigoIdPais;
        this.nombrePais = new SimpleStringProperty(nombrePais);
        this.capitalPais = new SimpleStringProperty(capitalPais);
        this.filtrarPais = new SimpleBooleanProperty(filtrarPais);
        this.dominioInternetPais = new SimpleStringProperty( 
        dominioInternetPais);
        this.listaCiudades = listaCiudades;
    }
.......
}

@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY) 
public class GS_TablaCiudades implements Serializable {

    @ GeneratedValue ( strategy = GenerationType.TABLE , generator = 
   "CodigoIdCiudad" )
    @ SequenceGenerator ( name = "CodigoIdCiudad" , initialValue = 1 , 
    allocationSize = 1 ) 

    @Id
    private int codigoIdCiudad;
    private SimpleStringProperty nombreCiudad;

    // creamos la relacion de  muchos a uno conla tabla Paises

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "codigoIdPais",nullable = true)
    private GS_TablaPaises paises;


    // establecemos la relacion de uno a muchos con la tablaComunidades
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = GS_TablaComunidades.class, mappedBy = 
    "ciudades", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<GS_TablaComunidades> listaComunidades = new 
    ArrayList<GS_TablaComunidades>();

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // constructor vacio
    public GS_TablaCiudades() {
        super();
    }   

    // constructor con parametros

    @SuppressWarnings("exports")
    public GS_TablaCiudades(int codigoIdCiudad, SimpleStringProperty 
    nombreCiudad, GS_TablaPaises paises,
    List<GS_TablaComunidades> listaComunidades) {
        super();
        this.codigoIdCiudad = codigoIdCiudad;
        this.nombreCiudad = nombreCiudad;
        this.paises = paises;
        this.listaComunidades = listaComunidades;
    }
}

@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY) 
public class GS_TablaComunidades implements Serializable {

    @ GeneratedValue ( strategy = GenerationType.TABLE , generator = 
    "codigoIdComunidad" )
    @ SequenceGenerator ( name = "codigoIdComunidad" , initialValue = 1 , 
    allocationSize = 1 ) 

    @Id
    private int codigoIdComunidad;
    private SimpleStringProperty nombreComunidad;

    // creamos la relacion de  muchos a uno con la tabla ciudades

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "codigoIdCiudad",nullable = true)    

    private GS_TablaCiudades ciudades;

    // establecemos la relacion de uno a muchos con la tablaLocalidades
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = GS_TablaLocalidades.class, mappedBy = 
   "comunidades", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<GS_TablaLocalidades> listaLocalidades = new 
    ArrayList<GS_TablaLocalidades>();

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // constructoer vacio
    public GS_TablaComunidades() {
        super();
    }

    // constructor con parametros   
    public GS_TablaComunidades(int codigoIdComunidad, SimpleStringProperty 
    nombreComunidad, GS_TablaCiudades ciudades,
    List<GS_TablaLocalidades> listaLocalidades) {

        this.codigoIdComunidad = codigoIdComunidad;
        this.nombreComunidad = nombreComunidad;
        this.ciudades = ciudades;
        this.listaLocalidades = listaLocalidades;
    }
}

controller program

package pruebas;

import java.util.List;
import com.jfoenix.controls.*;
import com.jfoenix.controls.cells.editors.TextFieldEditorBuilder;
import com.jfoenix.controls.cells.editors.base.GenericEditableTreeTableCell;
import com.jfoenix.controls.datamodels.treetable.RecursiveTreeObject;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBoxTreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTreeTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.ComboBoxTreeTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TreeItemPropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import personalModelo.entidades.GS_TablaCiudades;
import personalModelo.entidades.GS_TablaPaises;
import personalModelo.repositorios.GS_RepositorioTablaPaises;
import pruebas.TreeTableViewEditDemo.Gender;

public class PruebaPaisesTreeTableView extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        // Create column FullName (Data type of String).
        JFXTreeTableColumn<GS_TablaPaises, String> paisCol = new 
          JFXTreeTableColumn<GS_TablaPaises, String>("Pais");

        // Create 3 sub column for FullName.
        JFXTreeTableColumn<GS_TablaPaises, Integer> idPaisCol = new 
          JFXTreeTableColumn<GS_TablaPaises, Integer>("ID");

        JFXTreeTableColumn<GS_TablaPaises, String> nombrePaisCol = new 
          JFXTreeTableColumn<GS_TablaPaises, String>("Nombre");

        JFXTreeTableColumn<GS_TablaPaises, String> capitalPaisCol  = new 
          JFXTreeTableColumn<GS_TablaPaises, String>("Capital");

        JFXTreeTableColumn<GS_TablaPaises, String> dominioInternetPaisCol  = 
          new JFXTreeTableColumn<GS_TablaPaises, String>("D.I.");

        JFXTreeTableColumn<GS_TablaPaises, List> ciudadCodigoCol  = new 
          JFXTreeTableColumn<GS_TablaPaises, List>("ID");

        JFXTreeTableColumn<GS_TablaPaises, List> ciudadNombreCol  = new 
          JFXTreeTableColumn<GS_TablaPaises, List>("Nombre");

        JFXTreeTableColumn<GS_TablaPaises, List> ciudadColumna = new 
          JFXTreeTableColumn<GS_TablaPaises, List>("CIUDADES");

        // Single?  Column
        JFXTreeTableColumn<GS_TablaPaises, Boolean> filtrarPaisCol = new 
          JFXTreeTableColumn<GS_TablaPaises, Boolean>("Filtro");

        // Add sub columns to the pais
        paisCol.getColumns().addAll(idPaisCol, nombrePaisCol, capitalPaisCol, 
             dominioInternetPaisCol, filtrarPaisCol, ciudadNombreCol );
        ciudadColumna.getColumns().addAll(ciudadCodigoCol, ciudadNombreCol);

        // Se crea la lista con los paise de la tabla o clase entidad
        crearListaDePaises();

        // Root Item
        TreeItem<GS_TablaPaises> itemRoot = new RecursiveTreeItem<> 
               (observableListaPaises, RecursiveTreeObject::getChildren);

        treeTableViewPaises = new JFXTreeTableView<>(itemRoot);
        treeTableViewPaises.setEditable(true);
          // Add columns to TreeTable.
        treeTableViewPaises.getColumns().addAll(paisCol, ciudadColumna);

        //treeTableViewPaises.setRoot(itemRoot);

        // ponemos la tabla paises a la escucha
        tablaPaisALaEscucha();

        // ==== SINGLE?  (CHECH BOX) ===  
        filtrarPaisCol.setCellValueFactory(new 
        Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<GS_TablaPaises, 
        Boolean>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {

            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Boolean> 
            call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<GS_TablaPaises, 
            Boolean> param) {
                TreeItem<GS_TablaPaises> treeItemPais = param.getValue();
                GS_TablaPaises paisValor = treeItemPais.getValue();
                SimpleBooleanProperty booleanProp = new 
                SimpleBooleanProperty(paisValor.
                getFiltrarPais());  
                booleanProp.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? 
                    extends Boolean> observable, 
                    Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                         paisValor.setFiltrarPais(newValue);
                    }                         
                });
                return booleanProp;
            }
        });

        filtrarPaisCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn<
        GS_TablaPaises,Boolean>,TreeTableCell<GS_TablaPaises,Boolean>>() {
            @Override
            public TreeTableCell<GS_TablaPaises,Boolean> call( 
            TreeTableColumn<GS_TablaPaises,Boolean> p ) {
                CheckBoxTreeTableCell<GS_TablaPaises,Boolean> cell = new 
                CheckBoxTreeTableCell<GS_TablaPaises,Boolean>();
                cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                return cell;
            }
        });

        // Defines how to fill data for each cell.
        // Get value from property of Employee.
        idPaisCol.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<
        GS_TablaPaises, Integer>("codigoIdPais"));
        nombrePaisCol.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory< 
        GS_TablaPaises, String>("nombrePais"));
        capitalPaisCol.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory< 
        GS_TablaPaises, String>("capitalPais"));
        dominioInternetPaisCol.setCellValueFactory(new 
        TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<GS_TablaPaises, String> 
        ("dominioInternetPais"));
        filtrarPaisCol.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory< 
        GS_TablaPaises, Boolean>("filtrarPais"));

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        root.getChildren().addAll(treeTableViewPaises);

        stage.setTitle("TreeTableView (o7planning.org)");

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 450, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        //stage.show();
    }

    // metodo para cargar los datos de l tabla paises
    public void crearListaDePaises() {
        GS_RepositorioTablaPaises miRepositorio = new 
        GS_RepositorioTablaPaises();

        String query1 = "SELECT tablaP FROM GS_TablaPaises tablaP ";
        miRepositorio.miConexion.dameConexion().getTransaction().begin();
        TypedQuery<GS_TablaPaises> consultaElementos = miRepositorio. 
        miConexion.dameConexion().createQuery(query1,GS_TablaPaises.class);
        listaPaises = consultaElementos.getResultList();

        System.out.println("listaPaises: "+listaPaises.size());
        observableListaPaises = FXCollections.observableArrayList( 
        listaPaises);
        miRepositorio.miConexion.dameConexion().getTransaction().commit();
        miRepositorio.miConexion.cerrarConexion();
    }

    public void tablaPaisALaEscucha() throws Exception {
        treeTableViewPaises.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty(). 
        addListener((valor, valorNuevo, valorViejo) -> {
            System.out.println(" fila : "+treeTableViewPaises. 
            getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());

        });

    }

    // variable a nivel de clase
    private JFXTreeTableView<GS_TablaPaises> treeTableViewPaises;
    private List<GS_TablaPaises> listaPaises;
    private ObservableList<GS_TablaPaises> observableListaPaises;
    private CheckBoxTreeItem<Boolean> checkBoxLista;
}
```